# Does omitted variable bias affects coefficients for those variables that are not correlated with the error term? (When their is one variable that is)

Tags: regression, bias, omitted-variable-bias

Does omitted variable bias affects coefficients for those variables that are not correlated with the error term?  (When there is one variable that is.) I found two answers, but they appear to be contradictory, although I find both of their arguments convincing.  Anyone can clarify this?

https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.627.708&rep=rep1&type=pdf
pdf page 13 (or manuscript page 6): answers "Yes."

https://ipcig.org/evaluation/apoio/Wooldridge%20-%20Cross-section%20and%20Panel%20Data.pdf
pdf page 79 (or manuscript page 62): answers "No."

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "yes" as one can see by constructing a numerical example in Stata.
In this example, x3 is the omitted variable which is correlated with x2, but not x1.
However, the correlation between x1 & x2 makes the coefficient of x1 biased.  Nonetheless, it would be nice if there was a formula for the bias in x1.
set obs 10000
generate u1 = runiform()
generate u2 = runiform()
generate u3 = runiform()
generate u4 = runiform()
generate u5 = runiform()
gen x1 = 0.5*u1 + 0.5*u4
gen x2 = 0.5*u1+0.5*u2
gen x3 = 0.5*u2 + 0.5*u3
gen y = x1 + x2 + x3 + u5
reg y x1 x2